# Mysqli INSERT command followed by an UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I would like to have data inserted in one table, and data updated in another through prepared statements in *mysqli*. Trying the following only executes the INSERT command:

EDITED:

```
if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT bids_id, bid, fruit_volume FROM basket ORDER BY bid DESC")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($bids_id, $bid, $fruit_volume);                      
    while($stmt->fetch()) { 
        $stack = array($bids_id, $bid, $fruit_volume);
        array_push($all_fruits, $stack);    
    } 
    $stmt->free_result();
}
foreach ($all_fruits as $fruits) {
   if ($_POST["offer"] == $fruits[1] && $volume < $fruits[2]) {
        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO oranges (username, price, volume, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt2->bind_param('sdis', $user, $price, $volume, $today); 
        $stmt2->execute();

        $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE basket SET fruit_volume = ? WHERE bids_id = ?");
        $stmt3->bind_param('ii', 800, 1);
        $stmt3->execute();  

    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Remove the  $stmt2->close(); after your first query.IN fact remove all close conections put just one outside the loop

Comment: You are closing the $mysqli connection in the first go..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[bind_param](https://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) passes by reference not by value,so you need to have those values in variables before they can be referenced

```
$a=800;
$b=1;

foreach ($all_fruits as $fruits) {
   if ($_POST["offer"] == $fruits[1] && $volume < $fruits[2]) {
        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO oranges (username, price, volume, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt2->bind_param('sdis', $user, $price, $volume, $today); 
        $stmt2->execute();

        $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE basket SET fruit_volume = ? WHERE bids_id = ?");
        $stmt3->bind_param('ii',$a, $b);
        $stmt3->execute();  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
foreach ($all_fruits as $fruits) {
   if ($_POST["offer"] == $fruits[1] && $volume < $fruits[2]) {
        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO oranges (username, price, volume, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt2->bind_param('sdis', $user, $price, $volume, $today); 
        $stmt2->execute();


        $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE basket SET fruit_volume = ? WHERE bids_id = ?");
        $stmt3->bind_param('ii', 800, 1);
        $stmt3->execute();            
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the UPDATE command still doesn't work. I might need to add that a SELECT command is executed before the loop, accessing the same table as in the UPDATE command within the loop. I added the code above.